# Error when attempting to use the 'pop' method with a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to code a simple procedure, that simply reserves an input list (including nested lists).

The procedure itself -

```
def is_list(p):
    return isinstance(p, list)

def deep_reverse(input):
    result = []
    if len(input) == 0:
        return []
    for element in input:
        if is_list(element) == True:
            deep_reverse(element)
        else:
            appended = input.pop
            result.append(appended)
            print result
    return result
```

What I'm inputting to execute the procedure -

```
p = [1, [2, 3, [4, [5, 6]]]]
print deep_reverse(p)
print p
```

Result -

```
[built-in method pop of list object at 0xb752b0cc]
[built-in method pop of list object at 0xb7529c6c]
[built-in method pop of list object at 0xb7529cec]
[built-in method pop of list object at 0xb7529ecc]
[built-in method pop of list object at 0xb7529ecc]
[1, [2, 3, [4, [5, 6]]]]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No need to do `if is_list(element) == True:` when `if is_list(element):` suffices.

Comment: I found the accepted answer extremely helpful. Not an "extraordinarily narrow situation" at all. My guess is that this a common learning-curve error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`.pop` is a method. You have to call it:

```
appended = input.pop()
```

This will take the **last** element from `input`. If you want to take the **first** element, give it an argument:

```
appended = input.pop(0)
```

Comment: Cheers, such a simple mistake. Sorry about that.