# Python classes: find arrays whose sum equals a specific number

Tags: python, class

I am learning classes in Python and I am trying to do the exercise in which you are supposed to find the indices from the array of a list of numbers whose sum equals a target number. I am trying to do this way but I get "None" back.

```
class Find_arrays:
    
    def find_two_sum(self,lst, num):
        
        self.lst = lst
        self.num = num
        
        indices = {}
        
        for indx, num in enumerate(lst):
            
            indices.setdefault(num, []).append(idx)
        
        for k, v in indices.items():
            i = v.pop
            if n-k in indices and indices[n-k]:
                
                return i, indices[n-k].pop
            
            

            
            
a = Find_arrays()



print(a.find_two_sum([10,20,40],60)) 


Output: None
```

While if I try this way as simple function, it works well:

```
def find_two_sum(lst, n):
    indices = {}
    for idx, num in enumerate(lst):
        indices.setdefault(num, []).append(idx)
    for k, v in indices.items():
        i = v.pop()
        if n - k in indices and indices[n-k]:
            return i, indices[n-k].pop()


        
print( find_two_sum([3, 1, 5, 7, 5, 9], 10) )

print( find_two_sum([2,5,6,2,6,7], 12))


Output: 
(0, 3)
(1, 5)
```

Could you please give me a suggestion of what I am doing wrong? Thank you very much advance.

Comment: I tried but I get a "None" back.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) Your only `return` exists inside a `for` that's itself inside an `if`. What happens if the `if` condition is never satisfied?

Comment: Ok, never thought about that! I get it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you literally copy the "simple function" in your class, it works well:

```
class Find_arrays:
    def find_two_sum(self, lst, n):
        indices = {}
        for idx, num in enumerate(lst):
            indices.setdefault(num, []).append(idx)
        for k, v in indices.items():
            i = v.pop()
            if n - k in indices and indices[n-k]:
                return i, indices[n-k].pop()
```

this because in the class example you wrote `i = v.pop` instead of `i = v.pop()`

Answer (score 1):

```
class Find_arrays:

    def find_two_sum(self, lst, n):

        indices = {}

        for idx, num in enumerate(lst):
            indices.setdefault(num, []).append(idx)

        for k, v in indices.items():
            i = v.pop()
            if n - k in indices and indices[n - k]:
                return i, indices[n - k].pop()


a = Find_arrays()

print(a.find_two_sum([10, 20, 40], 60))
```

In the class version the variables n and num are not used in the same way as in the function version. The curved brackets after pop are missing twice.

I used the Pycharm IDE and its Python Debugger to find that. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/part-1-debugging-python-code.html. I also googled the error message. The google search led me to [Error when attempting to use the 'pop' method with a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214329/error-when-attempting-to-use-the-pop-method-with-a-list-in-python) .